# Calling AZ pipeline API from within pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I would like to call an Azure Pipeline API from within a stage of a Pipeline. Specifically to get the status of one pipeline from another so that a job can be forced to wait until the other pipeline is not busy.

I can call the API with a PAT locally. I am just not sure of the best way of passing auth from within the pipeline. Does the agent have some kind of built in auth mechanism with devops apis? Does the agent itself need a PAT and if so what's the best way of providing it one?

Comment: Found it - System.AccessToken was what I needed

Comment: Please post it as an answer below so it helps others in the community with similar asks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The System.AccessToken as detailed here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml was whart I required to call pipeline apis.